# How to set an element's attribute with JQuery and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making a dictionary. A page contains each letter of the alphabet:

```
<div class="letter" id="letter-a">
<h3><a href="#">A</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="letter" id="letter-b">
<h3><a href="#">B</a></h3>
</div>
```

*etc.*

On hovering over a letter, I want a tooltip to popup with some examples of words that begin with that letter.

The examples are stored in a seperate HTML file, like so:

```
<div class="letter" id="letter-a">
Abdication, Absolute, Acknowledge...
</div>
<div class="letter" id="letter-b">
Bacchus, Backbite, Beard...
</div>
```

*etc.*

The quickest solution I can think of is to use a $.get call on a link's title attribute, like so:

```
$('.letter a').hover(function(){
  var $this=$(this);
  var letter='letter-'+$this.text();
  letter=letter.toLowerCase();
  var url='tooltip-content.html #'+letter;
  $this.attr('title', $.get($(url).text()));
}, function(){
      //etc
  });
});
```

But this code just displays "[object Object]" in the tooltip instead of the example words.

Does anyone know how to fix it or can suggest a more elegant solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the object? It is a object that you have to extract the value. What if you call the innerHTML() function on the object?

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` returns a `jqXHR` object, not the text.

Try this:

```
$.get($url).done(function(txt) {
    $this.attr('title', txt);
});
```

p.s. using AJAX for each individual letter for this will be slow - it would be better to prefill the sample words directly onto the `title` attributes all in one go:

```
var letters = $.get('tooltip-content.html').done(function(html) {
     var $html = $(html);     // convert to object - don't put in the DOM
     $html.each(function() {  // iterate over each div
         var id = this.id;    // extract its ID
         $(id).attr('title', $(this).contents());
     });
});
```

(or something like that...)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response but this code displays the entire contents of tooltip-content.html in the letter's tooltip. I'm trying to extract the contents of the relevant div (e.g. div#letter-a when hovering over the "A" link) from tooltip-content.html and inject it into the letter's tooltip.

Comment: I've no way to replicate the AJAX request for testing - try looking at what's in `$html` and how the `.each` call iterates over it - have you perhaps got an outer div around the letter text that you didn't quote above?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I'll try to explain the process again:
When I hover over the "B" link on the main page (the first code snippet) there should be an AJAX call to tooltips-content.html (the second code snippet). The AJAX code needs to extract ONLY the html contained inside the #letter-b div and inject it into the title attribute of the "B" link I am hovering above on the main page so that the tooltip contains the examples of words beginning with the letter B (Bacchus, Backbite etc). Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1791841 it's completely clear.  I just suspect that the HTML from tooltips-content was incompletely quoted - the code _should_ have worked otherwise.

Comment: @user1791841 if the code you quoted above is complete then you _should_ modify it by wrapping a `<div>` around the whole lot and then using `$html.find('.letter').each(...)`.  The problem with not having a parent element is that you can't use selectors to find "top-level" elements.